# self.objects is empty in PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am trying to display data in different sections using PFQueryTableViewController. The code suggested in https://parse.com/questions/using-pfquerytableviewcontroller-for-uitableview-sections seemed to work, but I couldn't get the data to load on self.objects. Here is my code:

```
#import "AKAdminViewStudentsViewController.h"

@interface AKAdminViewStudentsViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *sections;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *sectionToClassMap;

@end

@implementation AKAdminViewStudentsViewController

@synthesize sections = _sections;
@synthesize sectionToClassMap = _sectionToClassMap;

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.parseClassName = @"Students";
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    NSLog(@"sections found: %@", self.sections); // returns null
    NSLog(@"sectionToClassMap: %@", self.sectionToClassMap); // returns null
    NSLog(@"objects in table: %@", self.objects); // this found to be empty
}

...

#pragma mark - Tableview methods

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
    PFQuery *queryStudents = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Students"];
    [queryStudents whereKey:@"student_admin" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

    if ([self.objects count]==0) {
        queryStudents.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }

    [queryStudents orderByAscending:@"class_name"];
    return queryStudents;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return self.sections.allKeys.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *className = [self classForSection:section];
    NSArray *rowIndicesInSection = [self.sections objectForKey:className];

    return rowIndicesInSection.count;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *className = [self classForSection:section];

    return className;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Students";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure cell
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", object[@"full_name"]];
    NSDateFormatter *formatDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatDate setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [formatDate stringFromDate:object[@"createdAt"]]];

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Helper methods

- (void)objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error
{
    [super objectsDidLoad:error];

    // Clear data before loading
    [self.sections removeAllObjects];
    [self.sectionToClassMap removeAllObjects];

    NSInteger section = 0;
    NSInteger rowIndex = 0;
    for (PFObject *object in self.objects) {
        NSString *className = [object objectForKey:@"class_name"];
        NSMutableArray *objectsInSection = [self.sections objectForKey:className];
        if (!objectsInSection) {
            objectsInSection = [NSMutableArray array];

            // Create new section for new class found
            [self.sectionToClassMap setObject:className forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:section++]];
        }

        [objectsInSection addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:rowIndex++]];
        [self.sections setObject:objectsInSection forKey:className];
    }
}

- (PFObject *)objectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *className = [self classForSection:indexPath.section];

    NSArray *rowIndicesInSection = [self.sections objectForKey:className];

    NSNumber *rowIndex = [rowIndicesInSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return [self.objects objectAtIndex:[rowIndex intValue]];
}

- (NSString *)classForSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.sectionToClassMap objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:section]];
}

@end
```

When I look at the NSLog data, `self.objects` is empty. I know this is the reason why data isn't displayed, and would like some advice to sort this out please! Thanks.

Comment: Is your query being executed (i.e. is `queryForTable` called)? Does the query have any matching data?

Comment: `[queryStudents findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
          {
              NSInteger count = [objects count]; if(count == 0)  queryStudents.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;}` write this line after [queryStudents whereKey:@"student_admin" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

Comment: @Paulw11 yup `queryForTable` was called. when I remove the overriding methods for `objectsDidLoad` and `objectAtIndexPath` it works well, though data is displayed in a single section.
@MohitPopat I can't call the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` method. The program crashes with error.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: @MohitPopat the PFQueryTableViewController superclass executes the query

Comment: I would expect self.objects to be empty in `viewDidLoad` because the query won't have executed yet. You need to single step through `objectAtIndexPath` to see what is happening there for a start

Comment: @Paulw11 I placed 2 breakpoints on `viewDidLoad` (at start and at `NSLog`), and one breakpoint each on `queryForTable`and `objectAtIndexPath`. Found something interesting. Actually the sequence the methods are called is `viewDidLoad` --> `queryForTable` --> `viewDidLoad`. It seems that `objectAtIndexPath` was skipped, so I may missed out something when I try to override the `objectAtIndexPath` method. Thought it's correct to override the method in the current file. What have I missed?

Comment: was `objectsDidLoad` called?

Comment: yes, it got called. Here's the log
`2014-08-28 14:21:45.041 Tutor[13072:60b] sections found: (null)`
`2014-08-28 14:21:45.042 Tutor[13072:60b] sectionToClassMap: (null)`
`2014-08-28 14:21:45.042 Tutor[13072:60b] objects in table: ()`
`2014-08-28 14:21:48.450 Tutor[13072:60b] objected loaded: ("data found")`
`2014-08-28 14:22:28.602 Tutor[13072:60b] objected loaded: ("data found")`
It's strange the `objectAtIndexPath` isn't called. Not sure if I have to call it manually.